# Recuperar e Imprimir valor seleccionado de um <select>

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho 1 `<select></select>` com varias opções e queria que através de jquery recuperasse o valor daquela que eu tivesse seleccionado e imprimisse na div teste, alguém me pode ajudar?

```
<select id="resultado_team2_CSGO">            
    <option value="Fnatic">Fnatic</option>
    <option value="tenvyus">Team EnVyUs</option>
    <option value="tsm">Team Solomid.</option>
    <option value="nip">Ninjas in Pyjamas</option>
    <option value="navi">Na`Vi</option>
 </select> 
<div class="teste"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode usar o evento `change` para isto.

```js
var resultado = $("#resultado_team2_CSGO");
var teste = $(".teste");

resultado.on("change", function (event) {
  teste.html(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="resultado_team2_CSGO">            
    <option value="Fnatic">Fnatic</option>
    <option value="tenvyus">Team EnVyUs</option>
    <option value="tsm">Team Solomid.</option>
    <option value="nip">Ninjas in Pyjamas</option>
    <option value="navi">Na`Vi</option>
 </select> 
<div class="teste"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado :D já resolvi

Answer (score 1):

Experimente isso, acho que já deve resolver:

```
$(function(){
    $('#resultado_team2_CSGO').on('change', function (e) {
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = this.value;
        $('.teste').text(valueSelected);
    });
  });
```

Segue o exemplo: **http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/t9n72u84/**

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu ;D